# Convert pandas data frame with mapping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame. Df1 which has the customer information:

```
Customer_Name    Demand
John               100
Mike               200
...
```

There is also a dictionary which has the map between customer name and customer code

```
Customer_Name    Customer_Code
John               1
Mike               2
...
```

I want to come up with a new data frame like Df1 but with customer code instead of name:

```
Customer_Code    Demand
    1              100
    2               200
    ...
```

To do this I am using the following code:

```
df3=data.replace({"customer_code": mapp})
Raw=data_m[['Demand','customer_code]]
```

it gives me the right result however it is very slow. I am wondering if there is more efficient way for such a mapping and conversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `merge` should do just fine.

```
df = df1.merge(df2)
df
  Customer_Name  Demand  Customer_Code
0          John     100              1
1          Mike     200              2
```

If you'd like to get rid of the first column, call `df.drop('Customer_Name', 1)`:

```
df.drop('Customer_Name', 1)
   Demand  Customer_Code
0     100              1
1     200              2
```

Or, index on columns:

```
df[['Customer_Code', 'Demand']]
   Customer_Code  Demand
0              1     100
1              2     200
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `df.map`

```
df1['Customer_Code'] = df1.Customer_Name.map(\
             df2.set_index('Customer_Name').Customer_Code)

df1
  Customer_Name  Demand  Customer_Code
0          John     100              1
1          Mike     200              2
```

Comment: No need to be petty. Your answer assumed that the second dataset was a DataFrame, which he said was a dictionary. I merely showed him how to convert it before merging as well as provided him with a method of keeping the columns he wanted in the order he wanted.

Comment: @EvanNowak Because it was a dataframe. I've never seen a "dictionary" that looks like a dataframe. Have you?

Comment: This is a complete answer giving two useful alternatives.  I'm not a fan of others posting identical content to mine.  +1 from me.

Answer (score -1):

You said your second dataset is a dictionary, so you'll want to convert that to a DataFrame before you merge the two:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_name, columns=['Customer_Name', 'Customer_Code'])

# Merge DataFrames and only keep Customer_Code and Demand
df3 = df1.merge(df2)[['Customer_Code', 'Demand']]

  Customer_Code    Demand
0             1       100
1             2       200
```